# How to add country name field based on mobile number using Mobile_Number using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-file

I am having logs in txt file contains fields below. I want to extract country code from mobile number and create (translate) into new field called country.

I checked with translate filter but not getting how to extract country code digits from mobile number field to use it on translate filter.

20 is the country code for Egypt,971 is the country code for bahrain.I want to do it for all country code.

Pls, suggest to me if it's doable for at least one country code so that it can translate for others and as all country codes are unique.

log-

```html
Mobile_Number: 201123123123User_id<....>
Mobile_Number: 971123123123User_id<....>
```

logstash filter-

```html
filter{
 grok {
        break_on_match => false
        match => {
            "message" => [
               "Mobile_Number: (?<Mobile_Number>[0-9]+)",
               "User_id(?<User_id>[0-9]+)"
                ]
           }}}
```

I found this topic on discuss elastic using ruby code in google phone lib,if any workaround is possible except this will be highly appreciable.

[Discuss Elastic-logstash-link-fileds-in-aggregate-filter](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-link-fileds-in-aggregate-filter/167272)

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating new fields such as "Country_Code" and "Country_Name" using logstash and enriching it based on "Mobile_Number" field is can be done using Ruby using phonelib library as stated earlier reply's link.

But the simple way was to use python script and parse the "Mobile_Number" field and create new fields using it by [phone number library](https://pypi.org/project/phonenumbers/).

It has 98% accuracy and enrichment speed can be improved by using bulk update API using [Elasticsearch helpers](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html)

Ref link-
[es bulk helper examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/104889/elasticsearch.helpers.bulk)

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-add-country-name-field-based-on-mobile-number-using-mobile-number-using-logstash/289588

Answer (score 0):

You can use below ruby code to convery phonenumber to country code

```
    gem 'phonelib'

require "phonelib"

def filter(event)
      s = Phonelib.parse(event.get("phonenumber"))
      event.set("CountryCode" , s.country)
end
```

Call the code in the logstash.conf file as below

```
 ruby {
      path =>  "/opt/bitnami/logstash/config/sam.rb"
      }
```

You will get country code , example US for USA

Make sure you are adding phonelib in the Gemfile